# Creating local yum repo for scylladb and install it within private network?

Tags: rpm, yum, scylla

I want to install scylladb on Centos and Redhat boxes. I found the installations instructions for the same [here](https://www.scylladb.com/download/open-source/scylla-centos_rpm/) but this involves copying a `.repo` file and then using yum to install it i.e. it uses public internet).

I want to create a local yum repo and don't want to connect to public internet but instead connect to my company network only. This would require that I have rpm available to myself, upload it in my internal system and then use yum instructions but I don't find the rpm for scylladb anywhere on the net.

Can somebody help on how to get the rpm or any workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My quick notes:

```
yum install createrepo
mkdir /path/to/mylocalrepo
  # Put all the RPMs in the mylocalrepo dir
cd /path/to/mylocarepo
createrepo .
```

then to use it:

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/localscylla.repo
```

## Enter this:

```
[scylla]
name=localScylla
baseurl=file:///path/to/mylocalrepo
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Then run

```
yum clean all
yum install scylla
```

of course you can mirror from your /etc/yum.repos.d/scylla.repo (that you got by registering) the repos using reposync
see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016